# Tools to assist managing the application promotion process in an enterprise environment

Tags: process-management

I am curious on how others manage code promotion from DEV to TEST to PROD within an enterprise.

What tools or processes do you use to manage the "red tape", entry/exit criteria side of things?

My current organisation is half stuck between some custom online forms type functionality and paper based dependencies to submit documents, gather approvals and reviews.

All this is left in the project managers hands to track what has been submitted, passed review, approved and advise management if there are any roadblocks that may need approval to be "overlooked" before an application can be promoted to the next environment.

A browser based application would be ideal... so whats out there? please show me that you googlefu is better than mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to find one that's good via google.  There is a vast array of tools out there for issue management so I'll mention what we use and what we woudl like to use.

We currently use serena products.  They have worked well for us in the past.  Team Track is our issue management and handles the life cycle of any issue we work on.  Version Manager is our source control and has the feature of implementing promotional groups like DEV TEST And PROD.  We use DEV, TSTAGE, TEST, PSTAGE and PROD to signify the movement from one to the other, but it's much the same.  The two products integrate nicely so that the source associated with the issues is linked, but we have no build process setup in this environment.  It's expensive, but it works well.

We are looking ot move to a more common system using Jira for issue management, Subversion for source control, Fisheye to link the two together and Cruise Control for build management.  This is less expensive, totaling a few thousand for an enterprise lisence  and provides all the same features but with the added bonus of SVN which is a very nice code version mangager.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different scenarios that I've experienced over the years:

Dev -> Test : There is usually a code freeze date that stops work on new features and gets a test environment the code that has been tagged/labelled/archived that gets built.  This then gets copied onto the machines and the tests go fine.  This is also usually the least detailed of any push.

Test->Prod : This requires the minor change that production has to go down which can mean that a "gone fishing" page goes up or IIS doesn'thave any sites running and the code is copied over again.  There are special cases to this where a load balancer can act as a switch so that the promotion happens and none of the customers experience any down time as the ones on the older server will move once their session ends.

To elaborate on that switch idea, the set up is to have 2 potentially live servers with just one server taking requests that the load balancer just sends all the traffic to one machine that can be switched when the other server has the updated code to go live.

There can also be a staging environment which is between test and production where the process is similar in terms of there is a set date when the promotion happens.

Where I used to work there would be merge days where a developer spent most of a day in Perforce merging code so that it could be promoted from one environment to another.

Now there are a couple of cases where this isn't used:

"Hotfixes" or "Hot patches" would occur where I used to work and in this case the specific files were copied up into the staging and production environments on its own since the code change had to get into Production ASAP since something broke in production or some new thing that had to get done that takes 2 minutes gets done.  In this case, the code change getting pushed in had to be reviewed and approved before going out.

Those are the different approaches I've seen used where generally there are schedules and timelines potentially have to be changed or additional resources brought in to make a hard date like if a conference is on a particular weekend that such and such is ready for that.

Of course in a few places there has been the, "Oh, was that broken? Let me see..." and a few minutes later, "No, see it isn't broken for me," where someone changed things without asking permission or anything where a company still has what they call "cowboy programming."

Another point is the scale of the release:
1) Tiny - This is the case where one web page goes up so that user X can do Y.

2) Small - A handful or so of files that isn't really complicated but isn't exactly trivial.

3) Medium - Where going from one environment to another requires changing a bunch of files and usually has scripts to move.

4) Big - Where there are scheduled promotions and various developers are asked for who is taking which shifts when the live push is done.  I had this in a case where there was a data migration to do in addition to a release of some new e-commerce sites.

5) Mammoth - Where everything is brand new including how this would be used.  I don't think I've ever seen one of this size but I'd imagine Microsoft or Google would have releases of this size.

Somewhere in that spectrum most releases fall and so how much planning and preparation can vary quite a bit and let's not forget that regulatory compliance can be its own pain in getting some things done.